# Create tile image with background using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to export tile image with background image.

without background I can generate it with following command

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 2.56 -i flower.jpg -filter_complex tile=8x4:margin=32:padding=32 output_0.png
```

Here is [flower image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlnYJ.jpg)

[Output Without background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsd3A.png)

But when I am trying with following command for adding background to tile, no success. can anyone correct my command?

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 2.56 -i bg.jpg -i flower.jpg -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=1280:720,setsar=1[in1],[1:v]tile=8x4:margin=32:padding=32[in2];[in1][in2]' -map '[in1]' -map '[in2]' output_0.png
```

Answer (score 0):

a) you need to use the overlay filter to paint one stream over another
b) options for an input go right before that input.

`ffmpeg -i bg.jpg -loop 1 -t 1.60 -i flower.jpg -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=1280:720,setsar=1[in1];[1:v]tile=8x4:margin=32:padding=32[in2];[in1][in2]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2' output_0.png`

If you want the space between the tiled photos to be transparent, add `color=black@0` to the tile filter.

Comment: getting no such filter error with this command

Comment: Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Comment: wait my mistake. Removed quote to run.

Comment: But still can you tell me the way if I need to remove static ratio 1280:720 and just add background to generated tile?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya Use the scale2ref filter.

Comment: @Gyan Can you give me one answer? 
FFmpeg not maintaining fps as input video frame rate. any reason?

Comment: Your command has no video, only image inputs.

Comment: No, right now i am asking about other command.

Comment: -i img_0.jpg -i img_1.jpg -i background_video.mp4 -loop 1 -t 15 -i first.jpg -filter_complex [2]split=2[color][alpha];[color]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0[color];[alpha]crop=iw/2:ih:iw/2:0[alpha];[color][alpha]alphamerge[ovrly];[0]scale=540:960[0_scalled];[1]scale=540:960[1_scalled];[3:v][1_scalled]overlay=enable='between=(t,7,15)'[base_video_1];[base_video_1][0_scalled]overlay=enable='between=(t,0,10)'[v0];[v0][ovrly]overlay=0:0 -t 15 -strict -2 -preset ultrafast out.mp4

Comment: Hi @Gyan need 1 more help.  Can you please check - https://stackoverflow.com/q/68311377/7783718

Comment: Hi Gyan @llogan Need help with other question
https://superuser.com/q/1686862/1104044